# How to check keys in two levels loop?

Tags: python, loops

I have data that looks like this:

```
{
    'METTS MARK': {
        'salary': 365788,
        'to_messages': 807,
        'deferral_payments': 'NaN',
        'total_payments': 1061827,
        'exercised_stock_options': 'NaN',
        'bonus': 600000,
        'restricted_stock': 585062,
        'shared_receipt_with_poi': 702,
        'restricted_stock_deferred': 'NaN',
        'total_stock_value': 585062,
        'expenses': 94299,
        'loan_advances': 'NaN',
        'from_messages': 29,
        'other': 1740,
        'from_this_person_to_poi': 1,
        'poi': False,
        'director_fees': 'NaN',
        'deferred_income': 'NaN',
        'long_term_incentive': 'NaN',
        'email_address': 'mark.metts@enron.com',
        'from_poi_to_this_person': 38
    },
    'BAXTER JOHN C': {
        'salary': 267102,
        'to_messages': 'NaN',
        'deferral_payments': 1295738,
        'total_payments': 5634343,
        'exercised_stock_options': 6680544,
        'bonus': 1200000,
        'restricted_stock': 3942714,
        'shared_receipt_with_poi': 'NaN',
        'restricted_stock_deferred': 'NaN',
        'total_stock_value': 10623258,
        'expenses': 11200,
        'loan_advances': 'NaN',
        'from_messages': 'NaN',
        'other': 2660303,
        'from_this_person_to_poi': 'NaN',
        'poi': False,
        'director_fees': 'NaN',
        'deferred_income': -1386055,
        'long_term_incentive': 1586055,
        'email_address': 'NaN',
        'from_poi_to_this_person': 'NaN'
    },
    'ELLIOTT STEVEN': {
        'salary': 170941,
        'to_messages': 'NaN',
        'deferral_payments': 'NaN',
        'total_payments': 211725,
        'exercised_stock_options': 4890344,
        'bonus': 350000,
        'restricted_stock': 1788391,
        'shared_receipt_with_poi': 'NaN',
        'restricted_stock_deferred': 'NaN',
        'total_stock_value': 6678735,
        'expenses': 78552,
        'loan_advances': 'NaN',
        'from_messages': 'NaN',
        'other': 12961,
        'from_this_person_to_poi': 'NaN',
        'poi': False,
        'director_fees': 'NaN',
        'deferred_income': -400729,
        'long_term_incentive': 'NaN',
        'email_address': 'steven.elliott@enron.com',
        'from_poi_to_this_person': 'NaN'
    },
    'CORDES WILLIAM R': {
        'salary': 'NaN',
        'to_messages': 764,
        'deferral_payments': 'NaN',
        'total_payments': 'NaN',
        'exercised_stock_options': 651850,
        'bonus': 'NaN',
        'restricted_stock': 386335,
        'shared_receipt_with_poi': 58,
        'restricted_stock_deferred': 'NaN',
        'total_stock_value': 1038185,
        'expenses': 'NaN',
        'loan_advances': 'NaN',
        'from_messages': 12,
        'other': 'NaN',
        'from_this_person_to_poi': 0,
        'poi': False,
        'director_fees': 'NaN',
        'deferred_income': 'NaN',
        'long_term_incentive': 'NaN',
        'email_address': 'bill.cordes@enron.com',
        'from_poi_to_this_person': 10
    },
    'HANNON KEVIN P': {
        'salary': 243293,
        'to_messages': 1045,
        'deferral_payments': 'NaN',
        'total_payments': 288682,
        'exercised_stock_options': 5538001,
        'bonus': 1500000,
        'restricted_stock': 853064,
        'shared_receipt_with_poi': 1035,
        'restricted_stock_deferred': 'NaN',
        'total_stock_value': 6391065,
        'expenses': 34039,
        'loan_advances': 'NaN',
        'from_messages': 32,
        'other': 11350,
        'from_this_person_to_poi': 21,
        'poi': True,
        'director_fees': 'NaN',
        'deferred_income': -3117011,
        'long_term_incentive': 1617011,
        'email_address': 'kevin.hannon@enron.com',
        'from_poi_to_this_person': 32
    },
    ...........
}
```

above is what my data looks like. I want to count how many poi is "True" in this dataset.

Please help me.

Comment: if you have the data in a Python object, do `print repr(data)` and post here. This way, it's going to have the correct dictionary syntax. People will not be able to help if they don't even know what the data looks like.

Comment: What you have shown us is not a valid dictionary. Print out your dictionary and post a minimal version of it so that we know exactly what we're dealing with

Comment: If you want to count things in Python, you might want to have a look at the [Counter](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you hold the data in a dictionary called `data`, you could write the following code that uses a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
print len([key for key in data if data[key]['poi']])
```

to display the number of items that have the `'poi'` attribute set to `True`.

Answer (score 1):

**Normal Iteration and Increase Counter Method:**

1. Iterate every item from the given dictionary with `for` loop and `items()` method.
2. Check `poi` key is present or not.
3. If `poi` have True value then increase true counter.
4. else increase false counter
5. Display result.

Demo:

```
ppl_info = {'METTS MARK': {'salary': 365788, 'to_messages': 807, 'deferral_payments': 'NaN', 'total_payments': 1061827, 'exercised_stock_options': 'NaN', 'bonus': 600000, 'restricted_stock': 585062, 'shared_receipt_with_poi': 702, 'restricted_stock_deferred': 'NaN', 'total_stock_value': 585062, 'expenses': 94299, 'loan_advances': 'NaN', 'from_messages': 29, 'other': 1740, 'from_this_person_to_poi': 1, 'poi': False, 'director_fees': 'NaN', 'deferred_income': 'NaN', 'long_term_incentive': 'NaN', 'email_address': 'mark.metts@enron.com', 'from_poi_to_this_person': 38}, 
'BAXTER JOHN C': {'salary': 267102, 'to_messages': 'NaN', 'deferral_payments': 1295738, 'total_payments': 5634343, 'exercised_stock_options': 6680544, 'bonus': 1200000, 'restricted_stock': 3942714, 'shared_receipt_with_poi': 'NaN', 'restricted_stock_deferred': 'NaN', 'total_stock_value': 10623258, 'expenses': 11200, 'loan_advances': 'NaN', 'from_messages': 'NaN', 'other': 2660303, 'from_this_person_to_poi': 'NaN', 'poi': False, 'director_fees': 'NaN', 'deferred_income': -1386055, 'long_term_incentive': 1586055, 'email_address': 'NaN', 'from_poi_to_this_person': 'NaN'}, 
'ELLIOTT STEVEN': {'salary': 170941, 'to_messages': 'NaN', 'deferral_payments': 'NaN', 'total_payments': 211725, 'exercised_stock_options': 4890344, 'bonus': 350000, 'restricted_stock': 1788391, 'shared_receipt_with_poi': 'NaN', 'restricted_stock_deferred': 'NaN', 'total_stock_value': 6678735, 'expenses': 78552, 'loan_advances': 'NaN', 'from_messages': 'NaN', 'other': 12961, 'from_this_person_to_poi': 'NaN', 'poi': False, 'director_fees': 'NaN', 'deferred_income': -400729, 'long_term_incentive': 'NaN', 'email_address': 'steven.elliott@enron.com', 'from_poi_to_this_person': 'NaN'}, 
'CORDES WILLIAM R': {'salary': 'NaN', 'to_messages': 764, 'deferral_payments': 'NaN', 'total_payments': 'NaN', 'exercised_stock_options': 651850, 'bonus': 'NaN', 'restricted_stock': 386335, 'shared_receipt_with_poi': 58, 'restricted_stock_deferred': 'NaN', 'total_stock_value': 1038185, 'expenses': 'NaN', 'loan_advances': 'NaN', 'from_messages': 12, 'other': 'NaN', 'from_this_person_to_poi': 0, 'poi': False, 'director_fees': 'NaN', 'deferred_income': 'NaN', 'long_term_incentive': 'NaN', 'email_address': 'bill.cordes@enron.com', 'from_poi_to_this_person': 10}, 
'HANNON KEVIN P': {'salary': 243293, 'to_messages': 1045, 'deferral_payments': 'NaN', 'total_payments': 288682, 'exercised_stock_options': 5538001, 'bonus': 1500000, 'restricted_stock': 853064, 'shared_receipt_with_poi': 1035, 'restricted_stock_deferred': 'NaN', 'total_stock_value': 6391065, 'expenses': 34039, 'loan_advances': 'NaN', 'from_messages': 32, 'other': 11350, 'from_this_person_to_poi': 21, 'poi': True, 'director_fees': 'NaN', 'deferred_income': -3117011, 'long_term_incentive': 1617011, 'email_address': 'kevin.hannon@enron.com', 'from_poi_to_this_person': 32}
}

poi_true = 0
poi_false = 0

for section, info in  ppl_info.items():
    if "poi" in info:
        if info["poi"]:
            poi_true += 1
        else:
            poi_false += 1

print "Result:\n POI True:%d\n POI False:%d "%(poi_true, poi_false)
```

Output:

```
$ python task4.py 
Result:
 POI True:1
 POI False:4
```

---

**By Collections Counter**

Demo:

```
import collections

result = collections.Counter()

for section, info in  ppl_info.items():
    if "poi" in info:
        result[info["poi"]] += 1 

print "Result:\n Dictinary: %s \n True:%d\n POI False:%d "%(result, result[True], result[False])
```

Output:

```
$ python task4.py 
Result:
 Dictinary: Counter({False: 4, True: 1}) 
 True:1
 POI False:4
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a plain loop over you data :

```
count_poi = 0
for v in somedict.itervalues():
    try:  # Only necessary if unsure about whether 'poi' is always a key
        if v['poi'] is True:
            count_poi += 1
    except KeyError:
        continue
```

Note that the try / except is not required if you know that your data is well formatted.

In that case you could also use the sorter syntax :

```
print len([v for v in data.itervalues() if v['poi'] is True])
```